# Command not triggering on button click

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

In my SL4 app, I'm trying to trigger a Command from a button.  The Command code is standard stuff that I have used without issue elsewhere, but I cannot get the Command to be called when I click the button.

This was driving me mental, so I eventually created a test page that had nothing on it but a button.  The data context of the page is set to my ViewModel, and the ViewModel has an ICommand property on it.  The DataContext is working as I can bind a textbox to a string property in the ViewModel.  It's so basic, I can include all the relevant stuff here:

From the XAML:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:x3.ViewModels"
```

...

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
<models:TestViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Button x:Name="TestButton" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Content="AAAAGHH" />
```

From the ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ICommand _testCommand;
  public ICommand TestCommand
  {
    get
    {
      _testCommand = new DelegateCommand(
        commandParameter =>
        {
          var testButton = commandParameter as Button;
        },
        (commandParameter) => {return true;});
      return _testCommand;
    }
  }
}
```

The DelegateCommand is part of Telerik.Windows.Controls.  If I put a breakpoint at
    _testCommand = new DelegateCommand
it gets hit when the page loads, but after that, I can click the button until my mouse wears out, and the command is never called.

For the sake of my mental health, I'd appreciate any help on offer.

Thanks

Mick

Comment: Mick, I don't generally write the commands myself but use the RelayCommands from GalaSoft.MvvmLight; which is open source. The syntax is pretty easy and there are a ton of tools in MVVM Light you can use in addition to the RoutedCommand class. Might that help?

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I kinda knew that I should be using one of the frameworks, but it means unpicking some of my existing code, and I have so far been lazy.  Maybe now is the time to bite the bullet, but i'd still like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: Also, Caliburn.Micro is a great framework for developing MVVM apps in WPF and Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get accessor for `TestCommand` is only called once - when the binding engine binds the `Command` of the `Button` to the `TestCommand` property.  Putting your breakpoint on the first line of the get, it should be expected that it only gets hit once.

What you need to do is put your breakpoint on the code that executes when your command gets run.  In your original example, this means break inside the delegate - i.e. on `return true`.

Edit: you can force the debugger to break in code as well using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`:

```
  ICommand _testCommand;
  public ICommand TestCommand
  {
    get
    {
      _testCommand = new DelegateCommand(
        commandParameter =>
        {
          var testButton = commandParameter as Button;
        },
        (commandParameter) => 
        {
          System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // Force debugger to break
          return true;
        }
      );
      return _testCommand;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That would explain a lot.  The code inside still wasn't running, but it seems that's due to some kind of fudge on my part.  If I still it down to its essentials, I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to isolate the problem, try using your own simple `ICommand` implementation, instead of Telerik's `DelegateCommand`.

If the problem still happens, you'll know it's somewhere around your XAML / data binding, and then I'd suggest you post more complete parts of your code so that someone here may help you.

If the problem disappears, you'll know it's something in Telerik `DelegateCommand` that decides not to call your lambda.

If you can post a more complete reproduction of the problem, it may also help. Because you posted only a minimal part of your code, and maybe the cause of the problem is missing from here...

Comment: Hi Ran.  In this instance there isn't much more code.  I've created the most basic page and ViewModel possible just to test it.  The XAMl has the usual xmlns statment, and the ViewModel has the necessary using statements, and a RaisePropertyChanged event, other than that, there's nothing else.  I removed the DelegateCommand, so that TestCommand simply had a get{return _testCommand}; statement in it, and if I put a breakpoint on the get, it doesn't get hit when the button is clicked

Comment: I followed your advice Ran, and used this http://johnpapa.net/5-simple-steps-to-commanding-in-silverlight to create a very simple commanding implementation, and it worked.  You've helped me ID the problem, so now I think the solution is to use one of the MVVM frameworks mentioned above.